# Removing scrubber and timestamp from YouTube video embedded in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I have a YouTubeView in an app I am making and I am trying to disable some of the video controls that are appearing, I have seen another App do it where it only displays the Play/Pause and Fullscreen icons. Some of the videos I am rendering are quite small (200x150) so the scrubber is useless and the time is actually overlapping itself.

The function I am using is:

```
- (YouTubeView *)initWithStringAsYouTubeId:(NSString *)idString frame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        self.frame = frame;
        self.delegate = self;

        // HTML to embed YouTube video
        NSString *embedHTML = @"\
        <html><head>\
        <style type=\"text/css\">\
        body {\
        background-color: transparent;\
        color: transparent;\
        }\
        </style>\
        </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
        <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body></html>";

        // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
        NSLog(@"%f", frame.size.height);
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, idString, frame.size.width, (frame.size.height*-1.0f)];

        // Load the html into the webview
        [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }
    return self;  
}
```

It loads and plays fine but I just want to disable the scrubber and times, I have tried ?controls=0 with no luck.

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

To be able to hide the scrubber and other controls, remove your `<embed>` tag and replace it with its `<iframe>` equivalent, like this (I've set it up using the parameters/attributes from your  example code):

```
<iframe id=\"yt\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?controls=0\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>
```

`'controls=0'` used with `<iframe>` will hide the controls for you.

In my brief experience with iOS embedded video, it seems like a solution to one problem often causes grief with something else that was previously working fine. Case in point: the above example hides the controls, but will overlay the video's title at the top-left of the UIWebView. The solution is to use this for your video's parameter list: '?controls=0&showinfo=0'

To see the scoop on the 'showinfo' parameter and others, check out the docs at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters  Not everything in the parameter docs works in the iOS `<iframe>`, but play around with some of them and you might find something useful.

For what it's worth (and this might be obvious to expert web coders, which I am not), you don't have to assign the 'id' attribute to be 'yt', but most every example I've seen does this; 'yt' is no magic value, you can set the id to be whatever makes sense to you.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you don't use MPMoviePlayerController?

Using MPMoviePlayerController, you would simply create a UIView in your nib that is the size you want to player to be. Then alloc/init the player and set its frame to be the frame of the view. Using MPMoviePlayerController gives you access to a property to show/hide the controls. Additionally, you get all the great delegate methods telling you when video stops, if the users goes into or out of full screen, etc.

Comment: As far as I know you cant use YouTube videos in the MPMoviePlayerController